# How is SQL server engine account able to access disk drive folder without permission?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2019

I have recently changed the SQL engine account to mydomain\sqlengine.

This evening I setup SQL audit into F:\audits. I'm surprised to see the SQL server is able to create a file in this folder without any permissions to this folder.

The above account is not a local admin.

How is SQL server engine account able to access disk drive folder without permission?

Answer (score 2):

By default users can write to subfolders on a drive.  eg

```
PS C:\> md audits


    Directory: C:\


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         9/23/2023   5:23 PM                audits


PS C:\> icacls audits
audits BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
       NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
       BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
       NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
       NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
PS C:\>
```

If you break inheritance on this this folder and remove the permissions for Authenticated users, SQL Server won't be able to write, and you'll have to add back permissions for the service account or the service virtual account (which is still active after you change the service account to a domain account).